# Perl/HTML - using an image in a button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use an image in place of a button that will call a Javascript function and move rows in an HTML table. The below code works for what I want it to, but I can't get it to display the image I want in place of a button.  I have also tried using an image tag with onClick event, which causes the Javascript function not to work as I am intending.

My Code:

```
(button(-name=>"Up", 
-img=>"images/Up_Arrow_icon.ico",
-id=>"UpButtonID", -myCustomRowNum=>$i,                             
-onClick=>"javascript:MoveRows(this.getAttribute('myCustomRowNum'));",)),
```

Comment: what language is that...

Comment: What is the generated html?

Comment: This is in Perl.

Generateed HTML: 

     <INPUT  onclick="javascript:MoveRows
     (this.getAttribute('myCustomRowNum'));"
      id=UpButtonID src="images/Up_Arrow_icon.ico" type=button
      value=Up name=Up mycustomrownum="7">

Answer (score 0):

The `button` HTML element does not have an `img` attribute. You'll want to nest an `img` tag within your `button`, or use CSS to give the `button` a background image.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how/where that is done in the Perl code above? I know how it's done in basic HTML, but I am new to Perl.